# Крестик очистки в IE 10

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, internet-explorer

В IE 10 в каждом поле `input` при вводе текста появляется крестик очистки, из-за чего едет верстка. Как убрать крестик очистки в IE 10?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

По умолчанию в IE 10 такой крестик ставится на `input`, убрать его можно так:

```
input::-ms-clear {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: спасибо! Всё сработало

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, этот способ не работает в том случае, когда в IE включён режим совместимости, так как IE недостаточно хорошо его эмулирует. Кто-нибудь знает другие способы убрать этот крестик? (Чтобы работало в режиме совместимости)

От себя добавлю, что также работает этот вариант:

```
::-ms-clear {
  width : 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Некоторые считают, что он даже [лучше](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs).

Вопрос по поводу совместимости остаётся открытым.

Comment: Перекрыть каким-нибудь элементом.

Comment: Нет, нужно именно избавиться от него.

Comment: Мб, `position:absolute; visibility: hidden;`?